# Rename all files with no extension in a given directory and sub-folders using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I need to write a script in PowerShell which renames all the files with no extension under a given directory and all subfolders. By renaming I mean to add an extension e.g. ".html" to the file which doesn't have it. 
So far I've tried to build something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\dev\blah' -Filter *. -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName ($_.FullName + ".html")
}
```

Comment: so, you may be best filtering with a `where-object` and point to the extension property of each file. Also, in your `-NewName` bit, point to the `$_.BaseName` and append to that, otherwise you'll get the full path with `$_.FullName` as the file name. Let us know any progress! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to exclude folders from the enumerated items. Use the switch `-File` if you're running PowerShell v3 or newer, otherwise add a `Where-Object` filter. Also, you don't need `ForEach-Object` since `Rename-Item` accepts pipeline input.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\dev\blah' -Filter *. -Recurse | Where-Object {
    -not $_.PSIsContainer
} | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name + ".html"}
```